# React native call API fetch

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

[image]

Help me to call this function please.
I want to get category count and category name from Wordpress API

```
CatName(item){
fetch('http://anbaetv.ma/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/'+item.categories)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => {
  this.setState({
    jsonData: json.count,
  });
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
}

renderItem = ({item}) => { 
return(
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}>
    <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 2,}}>
      <Image 
        style={{ width:100, height:80, margin:5}}
        source={{uri: item.better_featured_image ? 
          item.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url : 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?Text=NotFound'}}
      />
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:"center",marginLeft:5}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 15}}>{item.title.rendered}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 15,color:"red"}}>{this.CatName(item)}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
}
```

Comment: You did not mention the issue. Are you able to get a response from the API using fetch or is it that you have the response and it is not rendering correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call a function like that change

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 15,color:"red"}}>{this.CatName(item)}</Text>
```

to

```
<Text onPress={this.CatName(item)} style={{fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 15,color:"red"}}>click</Text>
```

This will call the function when we press on click text.

Hope this helps!